# Best convention to transpile javascript+jsx source-code in browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, babeljs, transpiler

I'm interested in knowing about what's the best convention, approach or best practice to transpile source code in the browser, as we have in projects like:

- Code Sandbox
  https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla
- Style guidist
  https://react-styleguidist.js.org

The approach these projects take, is a sort of Hot-reload, which is common use in most modern UI projects; it's not novelty and that's not what I want to discuss about; But if you think about the "same" concept in a production server, you might question what'd be the best approach to apply this principle, right? Would you POST the code Server-side?

We'd have to think about security! Maybe, workout which Browser supports JSX out of the box (there's none at a moment I can think of)? Request the user to write vanilla JavaScript and add React and React-Dom through script tags?! Or use a JavaScript transpiler like Babel and, use the Babel-Standalone to do it? Oh well, again, that's not advised, right?!